# Django Timezone aware DateTimeField default value timezone awareness error

Tags: django, django-models, timestamp-with-timezone

I am trying to add a DateTimeField to my django model with the maximum timestamp as default value. I already figured out, that the maximum timestamp in Django is 9999/12/31 23:59:59 unlike the maximum timestamp used in my postgres DB. When using this timestamp as default value for the field I get an `OverflowError: date value out of range` error. Therefore I tried the same with 9999/01/01 00:00:00 like so:

`start_time = models.DateTimeField(null=False, default=datetime.datetime(9999,01,01,00,00,00,tzinfo=utc))`

Now, when I apply this south migration to the database, I get the following exception:

`RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime (9999-01-01 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.`

When looking into the database, I see that my local timezone has been applied to the default value: `9999-01-01 00:00:00+01` This leads me to the conclusion, that somehow the timezone awareness is ignored by django, but I have no idea why that could be.

Additional Info:

Django TIME_ZONE is set to 'Europe/Berlin'

USE_TZ is True

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try calling `replace` on the datetime instead of passing the tzinfo into the `__init__` of the datetime. Taken from the [django docs:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects)

```
import datetime
from django.utils.timezone import utc

now = datetime.datetime(9999, 1, 1).replace(tzinfo=utc)
```

Comment: I thought that I tried it before, but this actually did the tric. Thank you.