# Django : date value out of range

Tags: python, django, datetime

Here its my django views.py line

```
currentTime = datetime.datetime.now()
freezeSlotBeforeTime="58"
cuerrentTimeToFreeze = currentTime - datetime.timedelta(minutes=int(freezeSlotBeforeTime))
```

on above line I got an error "date value out of range".

error:

```
OverflowError at /manager/summary/

date value out of range
```

Its work fine on ipython. but not in django views

```
currentTime = datetime.datetime.now()
In [11]: freezeSlotBeforeTime="58"
In [12]: cuerrentTimeToFreeze = currentTime - datetime.timedelta(minutes=int(freezeSlotBeforeTime))

In [13]: currentTime - datetime.timedelta(minutes=int(freezeSlotBeforeTime))
Out[13]: datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 13, 16, 24, 45, 711728)
```

How can I solve this error......

Comment: This code works for me. Are you sure the error is exactly in those lines? Can you post the full error message?

Comment: Post your stack errors traceback, please. Or, set breakpoint for debugging

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567329/django-timezone-aware-datetimefield-default-value-timezone-awareness-error