# Django DateField to infinity get 'OverflowError: date value out of range'

Tags: python, django, postgresql, datefield, django-postgresql

In my Django model  a DateField(representing an expiredate) could by infinite, i use as infinite date the calue of 'datetime.datetime.max', but what i get is

```
OverflowError: date value out of range
```

The db i'm using is postgresql.
Why this error? And is there any better approach for this?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567329/django-timezone-aware-datetimefield-default-value-timezone-awareness-error

Answer (score -2):

you need to install `pytz`, as per reported issue [20926](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20926)